# Trying to show or hide aspects of ng-include partial html template based on ng-init variables

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-init

I am trying to hide, show, or change the style of a partial html file based on the ng-init values.

My partial is:

```
<article class="preview {{size}}" ng-if="desktop">
    <a class="cover absolute" style="background-image:url(/images/samples/sample-image.jpg);">
        <div class="post-info absolute full-width padding">
            <h2 ng-if="artist" class="text-center">band name</h2>
            <h3 class="post-title section-spacer" ng-if="!artist">title of news artcle <span>2hrs</span></h3>
            <p ng-if="caption==true; !artist" class="post-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-preview-gradient"></div>
    </a>
</article>
```

In my main html page, I have this setup:

```
        <div class="row push-to-11 small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-3 section-spacer-large">
            <div class="column" ng-init="size='threequart-padding-bottom'; artist = true; " ng-include="'/partials/elements/posts/post-preview-regular.html'"></div>
            <div class="column" ng-init="size='threequart-padding-bottom'; artist = false; " ng-include="'/partials/elements/posts/post-preview-regular.html'"></div>
</div>
```

They are both currently getting attributes as if `artist = false`.

I have read multiple articles on when and when not to use ng-init, but I am still confused on why this would not update for each div. I am using this partial on multiple pages, so including it as a partial makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom directive instead:

```
var directive = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      artist: '=',
      size: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/partials/elements/posts/post-preview-regular.html'
  };
};

var module = angular.module('moduleName', [])
    .directive('directiveName', directive);
```

Then the markup becomes (after properly registering the directive module with your main module):

```
<div class="row push-to-11 small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-3 section-spacer-large">
  <directive-name ng-if="desktop" class="column" size="'threequart-padding-bottom'" artist="true"></directive-name>
  <directive-name ng-if="desktop" class="column" size="'threequart-padding-bottom'" artist="false"></directive-name>
</div>
```

---

Looking at your original markup, you might also need to add `caption` to the scope and pass it through, but it still shouldn't be too cumbersome.

Generally speaking, `ng-init` and `ng-include` feel more like last-resort sort of directives.  They aren't really meant for every-day use.  Even the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for `ngInit` say:

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses ...